# Как раньше называлось солнце?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Как я понимаю, слово "солнце" происходит от латинского слова корня Sol. А как называлось солнце у славян до того? Или же корень "сол" — общий для всех языков индоевропейской группы, а вовсе не заимствование?

Comment: Могу добавить, что латинский язык, как и старославянский, сохранили в себе куда больше праиндоевропейских слов (а также падежи, рода и мн.др.), чем изучаемый повсеместно в школах английский язык. Вот поначалу и удивляет сходство некоторых слов. Но эти слова нередко старше, чем славяне и латиняне.

Comment: По моему мнению, СОЛНЦЕ действительно пра-русского происхождения (или общеславянского, как говорят лингвисты).

Важный момент. Из  статьи Фасмера не вытекает, что СОЛНЦЕ - исконно-пра-славянское.  Расскажу, почему так думаю. Дело в том, что форма записи, которую пользует Фасмер (Трубачев?) - лукава сама по себе.

Comment: Когда он этимологизирует в одной куче ПРАСВЯВЯНСКОЕ, ЛАТИНСКОЕ или ГРЕЧЕСКОЕ построение, это не значит, что ПРАСЛАВЯНСКОЕ здесь имеет приоритет. Подумайте, ведь ГРЕКИ и ЛАТИНЯНЕ - это как бы реальные исторические "персонажи". А кто такие ПРАСЛАВЯНЕ? Когда они жили?
Этого никто не знает. А сама гипотеза о праславянах была выведена только лишь как временная точка опоры, хоть как-то обосновывающая общего предка.


Что же остается в сухом остатке?

Comment: А остается то, что из всего перечисленного у Фасмера реальную силу имеют лишь старшие культуры - греческая, латинская и т.д.


Понимаете уловку?
Да и на практике, в быту, вспомните, что именно оседает в мозгах у обывателя, "школьника" или преподавателя русского языка?

Оседает то, что весь русский язык состоит из греческих, латинских и западно-европейских слов. Это стало нормой, привычкой.

Поэтому-то подход в поиске и оценке исконных русских (общеславянских) слов должен происходить по иным критериям, не "фасмеровским".

Comment: В ПИЕ Солнце называлось ***soa̯ul*** (род. п. ***sa̯u̯ens***).

Answer (score 6):

Солнце - исконное праславянское, восходящее к древнейшим праиндоевропейским формам. 
Какие латинизмы?!

Происходит от праслав. формы *sъlnьсе, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. сълньце, ст.-слав. слъньцє (ἥλιος; Остром., Супр.), укр. со́нце, болг. слъ́нце, сербохорв. су̑нце, словенск. sо̑lnсе, чешск. slunce, словацк. slnce, польск. słоńсе, в.-луж. słónco, н.-луж. słуńсо. Праслав.* sъlnьсе — уменьш. образование от *sъlnь, ср. по́солонь (см.), ст.-слав. бєсльньнъ (ἀνήλιος; Супр.), а также солнопёк, солноворо́т. Образование аналогично се́рдце. Восходит к праиндоевр.* séh₂wl, ср.: лит. sáulė «солнце», латышск. saũle, др.-прусск. saule, др.-инд. svar- ср. р., вед. súvar (род. п. sū́ras) ср. р. «солнце, свет, небо», sū́ras, sū́rуаs «солнце», авест. hvarǝ (род. п. ẋvǝŋg ср. р. «солнце, солнечный свет», готск. sauil «солнце», кимр. haul, лат. sōl ср. р., греч. ἥλιος, гомер. ἠέλιος, дор. ἀ̄έλιος (и.-е. *sāvel), алб. hyll, уll «звезда» (*sūl-), далее сюда же готск. sunnô ж., др.-в.-нем. sunnа «солнце», древняя и.-е. основа на -l: -n. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Comment: Если русское "соло" связано с цветом (соловый конь), то откуда в его европейских аналогах возник смысл "единичности", "уединенности"? Не может быть чтобы соло-solo были неродственными корнями.  

Чисто логически можно предположить, что первоначальным был смысл "солнце", потом корень "соло" приобрел метафорические смыслы "цветом, как солнце", "один, как солнце".

Comment: >откуда в его европейских аналогах возник смысл... ? 

Это разные по происхождению морфы.

Comment: А почему вдруг они должны быть родственными? Ну я уточню "на всяк случай", конечно, но меня такая мысль ну ни разу не посещала.

А далеко-то не надо ходить...  
солово́й "желтовато-серый", солове́ть "мутнеть", укр. соловíти "мрачнеть (о взгляде)", русск.-цслав. славоочиɪе γλαυκότης = сѣроочие, сюда же соловцы́ мн. "небольшие волны с белыми гребешками". Родственно д.-в.-н. sаlо, salawêr " темный, мутный", др.-исл. so
 
со́ло муз., впервые у Куракина; см. Смирнов 279. Из ит. solo " один, одинокий, единственный", лат. solus – то же.
(Фасмер)  
Т.е. соловой - из гноманский, соло - из романских.

Comment: Ну, я думала, что общий смысл возник еще раньше германо-романского разделения, на уровне индоевропейских языков. Ведь слова очень похожи, все эти смыслы (соло - солнце - соль - ...) хорошо ложатся на исходный смысл "светило", которое и светлое (цвет), и одинокое.